# Should I use "a" or "the" to designate the particular one I'm going to talk about?

Tags: articles

In my previous posts, I wrote sentences like these:

> Here is **the** sentence from C. S. Lewis' *The Magician's Nephew*.
>
> Here is **the** piece from a video game.

Then I quoted one or more sentences from the book or game.

I don't really know if the definite article was correct there. Those sentences aren't the only ones present in the book or game, but, on the other hand, they're particular — they're the sentences I was going to talk about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are introducing these into the 'conversation' for the first time, you should use the indefinite article (or no article, '∅', if you are introducing several entities):

> Here is ***a*** sentence from *The Magician's Nephew*:
>    [...]
>
> Here are ***∅*** pieces from a video game:
>    [...]

If you have already mentioned them, or are distinguishing them as a defined subset of a set of entities you have already mentioned, you use the definite article:

> While reading *The Magician's Nephew* I encountered a sentence I couldn't parse. Here is ***the*** sentence:
>    [...]
>
> Most pieces of this video game are transparent, but here are ***the** ones I have difficulty with*:
>    [...]

Note that in the last example the italicized words define the pieces.